# Updating Python Version on Google Cloud Shell

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-shell

My Google Cloud Shell currently has python 2.0 which has been deprecated.

Does anyone have any code that would allow me to install python 3.7 in my Google Cloud Shell?

Thank you!

Comment: the first result google gives you, when you enter 'google cloud shell python 3': https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53468831.shtml ... please research yourself before asking here... also have a look at the [ask] section to see what topics you can ask about here

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Shell includes Python 3.7.3 as python3:

```sh
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
>>>
```

Comment: Is there any way to update that to Python 3.8, 3.9?

Comment: im glad you included the exit part of your command. I made the exact same mistake so many times.